# sendMessage from extension background or popup to content script doesn't work

Tags: background, google-chrome-extension, sendmessage, content-script

I know that question has been repeatedly asked in different ways, but I tried to go through all the answers (hopefully I didn't miss anyone) and none of them worked for me.

Here is my extension's code:

**manifest:**

```
{
"name": "test",
"version": "1.1",
"background": 
{ 
    "scripts": ["contextMenus.js"]
},

"permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>", "contextMenus"],

"content_scripts" : [
    {
        "matches" : [ "http://*/*" ],
        "js": ["jquery-1.8.3.js", "jquery-ui.js"],
        "css": [ "jquery-ui.css" ],
        "js": ["openDialog.js"]
    }
],

"manifest_version": 2
}
```

**contextMenus.js**

```
function onClickHandler(info, tab) {
    if (info.menuItemId == "line1"){

      alert("You have selected: " + info.selectionText);

      chrome.extension.sendMessage({action:'open_dialog_box'}, function(){});

      alert("Req sent?");

    }
}

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler);

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {

  chrome.contextMenus.create({"id": "line1", "type": "normal", "title": "I'm line 1",     "contexts":["selection"]});

});
```

**openDialog.js**

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {

  if (msg.action == 'open_dialog_box') {
    alert("Message recieved!");
  }
});
```

The two alerts of the background page work, while the one of the content_script doesn't.

console log's message: Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

Where is my fault?

Comment: You should use `chrome.tabs.sendMessage()` to send messages to content scripts, not `chrome.extension.sendMessage()`.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

In your background page you should call

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "open_dialog_box"}, function(response) {});  
});
```

instead of using `chrome.extension.sendMessage` as you currently do.

The `chrome.tabs` variant sends messages to content scripts, whereas the `chrome.extension` function sends messages to all other extension components.

Comment: Thanks you. That's correct except that `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` [must specify which tab to send it to](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html). So the solution is change to: `chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tabs){ 
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {action: "open_dialog_box"}, function(response) {
   });
  });`

Comment: We can even pass "null" instead of "{active: true}" to point to the current tab.

Comment: what should write to receive on content-script.js ?

Comment: @KushalJain I just figured this out. In your content script JS file, you'll want to add an event listener like this: `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( (message, sender, sendResponse) => { /* Code Here */ } );`

`message` is the parameter containing `{ action: "open_dialog_box" }` or whatever you send. `sender` is an object containing your Chrome extension's ID. `sendResponse` is the parameter containing `function(response) {}` or whatever function you pass in to be called once the message is handled.

Comment: I don't get it... How can I send JSON or text between `content_script.js` and `background.js` ??

Comment: add another optional parameter since method signature has been changed

Comment: This solution did not work for me. I am following the documentation exactly 
I copied all the code from https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging
This is very simple example but could not get it right.
Getting error  Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
Any ideas

Comment: @umsateesh Did you get any solution?

Comment: just going to put it here because i had no idea: `tabs.query` and `tabs.connect` **do not require the tabs permission**.

Comment: @umsateesh Did you solved it?

Comment: Make sure the content-script is yet loaded when sending the message

Comment: Anyone coming across this in 2023, after 10 years. Yes, it works!

Answer (score 26):

@apsillers is correct.
Also don't forget to return true in your content-script listener or it might close too early.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log(message)
    return true
});
```

Comment: This fixed it for me – I was getting no response, but adding `return true` got it working.

Comment: I swear, on SO the simplest answer is usually the right one.  I can't believe this is what fixed this issue, but it did.  Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 7):

The problem with the provided solutions is that they raise other errors (Which break my Google Chrome)

@apsillers solution works but the callback raises errors!

How it should look like

// Background.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {action: "open_dialog_box"});  
});
```

Now in Content scripts as provided by @Ronan Ca which builds upon @apsillers solution. It is Not ideal to return since we removed the callback from the background script.

// ContentScripts.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
console.log(message)
// return true <- this and the callback in background.js are what caused a crash in extensions page of my Google chrome
});
```

The background console won't open If I try to do it with callbacks. (It's that bad of a crash)

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of a background script that sends a message to the content-script file.

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id,"your message");
```

**content-script/content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (response, sendResponse) {
          console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me in manifest V3. Send message from background script to content script.

```
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(sender.tab.id,"your message")
```

Answer (score 1):

My use-case required sending a message to the background script from a webpage. I used `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal` to catch this message.

Inside of this listener I was basically forwarding the message over to my content script so it could do its thing, but I could not figure out why my content script onMessage listener wouldn't catch the message.

Turns out by waiting for 1 second before sending the message from the webpage (I was basically doing it on load) I was able to see the message hitting my content script.