# beginner to chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to learn chrome extensions and I am trying to build a simple one which tries to find if there are forms or not in webpage.

My code is as simple as possible and the following snippet is content script - `javascript.js` and popup page - `index.html`.

```js
function sendMessage() {
  chrome.extension.sendMessage({
action: "findurls"
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var show = document.getElementById('show');
  show.addEventListener('click', findValidForms);
  });

const findValidForms = () => {
  let list = [];
  let message = "Available forms are: \n ";
  let forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
  if (forms.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      list.push(forms[i].action);
      message += `<a href="${list[i]}">${list[i]}</a><br />`;
    }
  }
  else {
    message = "no forms";
  }
  alert(message);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>testing</title>
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


</head>

<body>
    <div id="cgi">
        <div class="heading">
            <h3 center> Test title </h3>
        </div>
  
    <div id='ah!'> </div>
    <button id='show'>find forms</button>
    
    <script src="jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

```
manifest:
"manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "form",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "find form url ",
    "icons": {
        "16": "chrome_16.png",
        "32": "chrome_32.png"

    },

       "background": {
     "scripts": ["background.js"],
     "persistent": false
  },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "javascript.js",
                "jquery-3.5.0.min.js"
            ],
            "css": [
                "style.css"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "chrome_16.png",
        "default_popup":"index.html",
        "default_title": "test"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ]
}

 background.js:
  chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse)
{ 
    if (request.action == "findurls")
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({ file: 'test.js' });
}
```

);

Thanks

Comment: I've edited your question to include the [google-chrome-extension] tag, which will help narrow the audience to those people who know extensions.

Comment: I am sorry if I missed it but... what is your question exactly ?

Comment: how to make it work as chrome extension..i have installed it and when i run it it doesn't work..or to explain it better it shows extension id instead of form urls.

Comment: @sofia, your event listen given in the content script but the button was placed in popup page. Button click even listener should be moved to popup page script and whenever the button clicked, it will have to send a message to current tab's content script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicked the button placed in `index.html`, the extension should send a message to content script - `javascript.js` in your solution. So the content script needs a event listener that monitors the message triggered from background script. Once it's arrived, the corresponding method should be executed.

Here is [the quick link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265403/passing-message-from-background-js-to-popup-js/43485784#43485784) to resolve but let me briefly describe here.

1. Create a js file (ie `index.js`) and inject into your `index.html`. *(honestly, `popup.html` and `popup.js` will be better than the current name - **index**)*. Give this code into the `index.js`
2. In your content script - `index.js`, add the code to listen message sent from the popup page's script (`index.js`) with handler the current function you created. (Original function name was `Forms`)

`popup.js`

```js
const sendMessage = () => {
    chrome.tabs.query(
        {
            active: true,
            currentWindow: true
        }, (tabs) => {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
                tabs[0].id,
                {
                    action: "get-urls"
                }, (response) => {
                    console.log(response)
                }
            );
        }
    );
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var geturls = document.getElementById('btn-get-urls');
    geturls.addEventListener('click', sendMessage);
});
```

`content_script.js`

```js
const FindAllForms = () => {
    let list = [],
        message = "Available forms are: \n ",
        availableForms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    if (availableForms.length > 0) {
      for (var i = 0; i < availableForms.length; i++) {
        list.push(availableForms[i].action);
        message += "<a href=" + list[i] + ">" + list[i] + "</a>" + "\n";
      }
    }
    else {
      message = "no forms";
    }
    alert(message);
}
  
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
   (request, sender, sendResponse) => { 
        if (request.action == "get-urls") {
            FindAllForms()
            sendResponse({'success': true})
        }
    }
);
```

In the popup script, you should send a message to current/active tab's content script [as this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245334/sendmessage-from-extension-background-or-popup-to-content-script-doesnt-work#answer-14245504).

I hope this will help you.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks @Perfect! I will try your suggestion.A general query though:Why background.js is necessary?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I got confused in the process.So, I have my html file (index.html) with the button. My javascript file (javascript. js) in my case (--I will change the name later) and in that I have already my function and the event listener for the button.  when I click it now it works but it shows my extensions Id. To fix it I must create a background. js file to write a message. But what kind of message is that?? Thats where I am getting confused.

Comment: can you tell once more what i have to do??i haven't made any progress form yesterday because i don't know what kind of message i must write and where.All this situation is confusing! Thank you!

Comment: My latest actions:Created background.js and i used messages but nothing works.I do not know if the message is right.Please,if anyone knows tell me how to fix it.Thanks

Comment: @SofiaGiannou, sorry for my late response. You should send message from background script to active tab.

Comment: so everything i have done is wrong?I just can't find a simple example for this and sorry if i am disturbing you a lot

Comment: No, that's okay. If you are available, I will give you some help on it via some messenger like skype or anything else. I think there was a tool to chat each other here on stackoverflow but couldn't find.

Comment: I added a link to an answer. Here again.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245334/sendmessage-from-extension-background-or-popup-to-content-script-doesnt-work#answer-14245504

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216146/discussion-between-sofia-giannou-and-perfect).

Comment: it's working!!Thanks!I have 2 queries though:When i run my code in console it actually shows the forms as clickable urls.In alert the form urls are as text..is there a way to have clickable urls in alert?And the second query is:if i add a second button i must do the same thing for it again?Send message to backgoriund etc to make it work?